# Error with updating new APK on the developer's console

Tags: android

I have been trying to update my app with the new version and I run into this problem on the developers console. I have such error:
[image]

I checked with the version of my previous version to see if I was doing something wrong, but it was the same.

[image]

Here is my updated xml file

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:icon="@mipmap/iron"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:versionCode="100"
        android:versionName="2.0"
        >
```

Comment: Your previous version code is 1, simply change it to 2.

Comment: I've tried 2,3,4,5 and so on, Finally got tired and put in 100, like in the manifest. android:versionCode="100"

Comment: You have to make sure you update *both* the `versionCode` and `versionName`.

Comment: Check build.gradle for versionCode as well as XML, build.gradle has basically replaced the XML versionCode for apps using the gradle build system

Comment: I'm so sorry, I was messing with the Manifest file instead of the build.gradle file, such a newbie question. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you already have version 1. in the play store. To be able to update it, you need to change the version number in the `build.gradle` file in your android project.

Sync your project, then generate the new APK.

I doubt if just updating the manifest will work.

Comment: Damn, thanks a lot. I was trying to change the "android:versionCode="2" in the manifest since two hours.

Comment: Updating the manifest didn't suffice. Changing the gradle too helped. I'm gonna leave this question here just in case newbies like me faced the same problem, this could be of some help.

Answer (score -1):

In order to define your app version dynamically, specify a custom method with def and call it, as such in your .gradle:

```
def computeVersionName() {
    return "2.0"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 12
        versionName computeVersionName()
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```